# Splitting geometry of two models which are merged together

Tags: modeling, texturing, mesh

I have a obj file which contains a basic model with two various versions of it you can see here:

[image: Osun model].

This model contains a grey/teal/blue model (Darkwitch) with their textures and a purple/orange one (Kuralak). Unfortunately both versions have different geometry like the horns and shoulder which only belong to the Darkwitch. Looking through the texture files you can see that there are several materials for this model:

[image: Textures]
Even though I know that it really depends on the model/file itself I would like to know how I can have a look at the different geometries trying to separate them? Or is it somehow possible to make all other textures transparent so only the Kuralak model becomes visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have one mesh object and you want parts of it to be hidden in object mode depending on some chosen options you can use a mask modifier.

To make use of the mask modifier you first setup some vertex groups, you may be able to do this by selecting based on the material applied, otherwise you need to select different vertices and add them to a group.

Once you have the vertex groups setup you can add a mask modifier for each group, then you can easily turn on/off the different parts.

[image]

The mask modifier shows only vertices in the selected group, clicking the arrows next to the vertex group name inverts this so it hides the chosen vertices.

Comment: Apparently there were no vertex groups at all so I might have to create one based on the materials applied. Do you have more information on how to do so?

Comment: That's good for a new question - create a vertex group and assign the selected vertices to the group.